# Unknown column 'tx_bundesligasimulator_domain_model_player.name' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, typo3

Bundesliga-Simulator is an self-created extension.

**The issue:**
Unknown column 'tx_bundesligasimulator_domain_model_player.name' in 'field list'.

**The problem:** That column should nowhere even be called. I deleted all caches, deleted all files in temp directory and restored it, compared the database with the TCA, truncated the cache tables in the database..... Can´t find this ugly issue. I even searched for it in the project structure with `egrep -rni -e` (!), nothing..... don´t know further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check your `ctrl` properly?

This sometimes happens to us when we forget to clear fields like "label", "searchFields", etc ...

Comment: `ctrl`is a section of your TCA file(s) : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can't comment i don't have the right reputation -.-.

Check your Typoscript maybe there is some CONTENT or RECORD cObject. You can search for the table "tx_bundesligasimulator_domain_model_player" with ctrl+f under template->template analyse->full template.

The error shows up also if the extension is disabled and you have cleared the caches in the install tool?

Comment: in that extension, i´m not using so much typoscript. it´s just to save template-, layout-, and partialpath´s...

Answer (score 0):

If you have this field in your domain model or your tca configuration, TYPO3 tries to fill the model with the data. Remove this field if it doesn't needed from your domain model and tca.

Comment: Which TYPO3 Version is used?

Comment: it is version 7.6.18